# Alinhar texto dentro de <select> no Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Estou tentando alinhar o texto dentro de um `<select>` porém o mesmo só é alinhado(por padrão) utilizando os navegadores Chrome e IE11(por incrível que pareça), somente no FF(v27.0.1) que o texto fica no topo.

Já tentei utilizar `vertial-align:middle` mas não mudou em nada.

Gostaria que fosse alinhado verticalmente sem usar um `padding-top` para o elemento pois o mesmo desalinha nos outros navegadores.

HTML

```
<select name="disciplina" id="disciplina">
    <option value="00">Disciplina</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
select {
    width: 200px;
    height: 38px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alessandroaje/UHBag/1/).

Comment: realmente é complicado isso, se voce adicionar um padding fica desalinhado nos outros

Comment: Realmente postei uma resposta com `padding` e não resolveu. Agora fiquei curioso com a solução

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tente usando o `padding-top` e `padding-bottom` por exemplo **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kH377/)**

### CSS

```
select {
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

documentação: **[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)**

Comment: Bom jovem, esta explícito que não pode ter um valor pre definido no `padding-top`, portanto sua resposta deve ser ajustada.

Comment: Sim, agora que você falou acabei de ver, é que ele fez a edição falando que não podia usar padding bem depois de eu ter enviado a resposta... Bom dia

Comment: Sua resposta foi criada a  5 minutos e a edição a 16 minutos, portanto você estava ciente da edição ou não teve o trabalho de ler a necessidade do Alessandro Gomes, Jovem.

Comment: Eu gostaria de não depender do padding, porém neste formato que você passou eu não preciso calcular a altura para saber o padding top, só preciso dar o mesmo padding top e bot, por enquanto está é a solução para o meu caso, vou fazer mais alguns testes aqui e caso eu não ache uma solução sem padding, marco como resposta Ok. Valeeu

Comment: Ok, também peço desculpas por ter insistido no padding mas essa foi a unica solução que consegui achar... @EduardoBentoRochaJunior

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha sua resposta é a solução que ele procurava, mas ele não queria um valor absoluto e acabou usando. :D

Comment: @EduardoBentoRochaJunior eu não queria um top absoluto, porém da forma que ele passou, eu só preciso colocar o mesmo top e bot que o mesmo ficará sempre ao centro, sacou? Por isso que funcionou para mim..

Answer (score 4):

Fiz um exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scofieldm1/BUBwd/):

HTML

```
<div class="styled-select">
   <select name="disciplina" id="disciplina">
      <option>Here is the first option</option>

   </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 200px;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 1px solid #CCC;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 34px;

   }
```

Peguei a referência [deste site](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/).

Comment: eu havia tentando fazer isso mas não tinha funcionado, mas a sua tentativa funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Que bom! tentei usar diversos métodos, porem esse foi o melhor.

Comment: Dica: se você explicar *porque* seu código soluciona o problema e colocar links para documentação, as chances de ter a resposta aceita *aumentam muito*.

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode usar desta formando e deixar o texto afastado da esquerda.

**CSS**

```
select {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
}
```

ou

```
select {
    width: 200px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Observe: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alessandroaje/UHBag/1/)